# After upgrading Spring Boot from 2.5 to 3.1.2 version, package org.cache2k.integration is not found

Tags: spring-boot, redis, build.gradle

While building the project getting below error:

> error: package org.cache2k.integration does not exist
> import org.cache2k.integration.CacheLoader;

Screenshot of error

[image]

Setup details under build.gradle file:

```
targetCompatibility = '17'

sourceCompatibility = '17'

plugins {

    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2' apply false
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.2' apply false      
}
```

Comment: Thanks @James for formatting the content.

Answer (score 0):

org.cache2k.integration was deprecated. see here https://cache2k.org/2/0.0.Final.html. use org.cache2k.io instead

Answer (score 0):

Can use cache2k-spring, for example:

```
implementation group: 'org.cache2k', name: 'cache2k-spring', version: '2.6.1.Final'
```

Comment: What does this accomplish exactly? Also, does this go in the Gradle file?